# how to use aws lambda to write data stored in S3 to Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where data is being written in S3. what I wish to do is process this data and store in dynamo db. I am using lambda to handle s3 object. Any insight on how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add S3 trigger so your lambda will be automatically invoked whenever a new object is added.

In my case, the lambda parses CSV files and puts the records to the DynamoDB predefined table.

[image]

2. Here's an example of how the lambda would look like (read my comments):

https://gist.github.com/johnib/14b090d0883ee2d2fb56dd3ac3c82f9b

Let me know if I missed anything.